# code work for once and stop

Tags: jquery

```
<script>
    $('.alert_success').hide();
    $('.alert_error').hide();
    $('.trash').click(function(){
        var r=confirm("wil delete")
        if (r==true)
        {
            var id = $(this).attr('id');
            $.post('ajax/del_art.php',{id:id},function(data){
                $("#concon").fadeOut(1000);
                $('.alert_success').fadeIn(1000);
                $('.alert_success').html(data);
                $('.alert_success').delay(5000);
                $('.alert_success').fadeOut(1000);
            });
        }
    });
```

When I click to delete, the code works for once (id #concon) and stops.  How can replace `#concon`  with `$(this)`?

I want the item to delete and hide when I press delete.

http://behiramp.com/admin/article.php

Try delete any post it will work fine.  Try delete next post it will work fine.

now  i mack

```
<script>
$('.alert_success').hide();
$('.alert_error').hide();
$('.trash').click(function(){
 var r=confirm("سوف يتم حذف الموضوع الى الابد!")
  if (r==true)
    {
      id = $(this).attr('id');
        $.post('ajax/del_art.php',{id:id},function(data){
         if($(".concon").hasClass(data))
           {
              $(".concon").fadeOut(1000);
              $('.alert_success').fadeIn(1000).html(data).delay(3000).fadeOut(1000);
           }

         });
  }
```

});

in hasclass it back with "date" not content data how can  .hasClass() back with Variable

Answer (score 1):

i see you're using the same id multiple times, which is a big no no

try changing this

```
$("#concon").fadeOut(1000);
```

to this

```
$(".concon", this).fadeOut(1000);
```

and then on your DOM change this

```
<tr id="concon"></tr>
```

to this

```
<tr class="concon"></tr>
```

Comment: did you change your dom to reflect a class instead of an id?

Comment: I'm sorry, I can't seem to test with the link you provided (there are no articles to test the delete feature). I can provide advice based on every class hiding. You need to find the parent element of this concon class and then reference it with this line $(".concon",this).fadeOut(1000); "this" should actually be the parent element. e.g. $(this).parents("td").fadeOut(1000);